# how to build Spring BulkEmailer web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring.I had a doubt regarding sending mails.How can i send a bulk of mails from spring based web application in which i have a requirement in my project.
                          I have no idea on this please suggest me something which is helpful
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should think other way around. How to implement bulk of emails using java and then improve your code using spring.

Comment: This isn't really an answer but I would think very carefully about implementing your own bulk email sender. It's a much harder problem than it sounds at first. Some of the large bulk mail sending companies have published guides to illustrate the complexity.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to get blacklisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send bulkemails using spring and it also offers scheduling a mails to multiple reciepts refer this example

[refererence](http://shahmukesh.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/spring-integration-with-quartz-for-sending-bulk-e-mails/)

You can also go through some of the real sites which are already exists and using for marketing with bulkmails [check this](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp)

so that you can get an idea to work on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I usually offer some code but in this case I would just copy-paste from [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/send-email-with-spring-javamailsenderimpl-example/) tutorial.

Spring has very little in terms of mailing support (which is found in the [context-support](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support) module), which itself is just a wrapper over the [javax.mail](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail) package.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would use a service like Amazon SES, which helps keep your email messages out of spam boxes.
2. Install an MTA (like Postfix) in Satellite Mode on your local machine. This will relay emails to Amazon SES.
3. Use JavaMail to send email messages to localhost, and they will go to your MTA queue, and get sent to Amazon.
4. Make sure you are complying with anti-spam legislation: http://www.business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business